# Cannot retrieve one of my applications in the list of Azure AD applications I get using Graph API

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, service-principal

I want to delete a service principal (an Azure AD application) from the list of applications of a given customer, so I am query for the list of Service Principals in the tenant with:
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/servicePrincpials

The issue is that I can see many applications but not the one we are working on. This application is not added manually through the Azure Portal but through an Admin consent dialog shown to the customer to grant the requested permissions to our application to access the Azure AD.

If I copy the object-id from Azure Portal I am able to get the application, or to delete it using the graph api, but I am not able to get it through the list of applications.

Comment: Solved: I was not getting the full list of applications. Using "$top=999" I get a huge list of applications and between then the one I am looking for. Also I see I can use filters to get a shorter list filtering by appId for example (see [link](https://nilesh.live/2017/10/26/using-optional-query-parameters-with-microsoft-graph-api-part-2/)). No idea how to close this issue since its solved.

Comment: Hi, you could post it as an answer, then it can help other community members.

Answer (score 0):

Solved: I was not getting the full list of applications. Using "$top=999" I get a huge list of applications and between then the one I am looking for. Also I see I can use filters to get a shorter list filtering by any property (see [link](https://nilesh.live/2017/10/26/using-optional-query-parameters-with-microsoft-graph-api-part-2/)) like displayName: https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/servicePrincipals?$filter=displayName eq 'name'